# At what point do you convert your fork into your own repository?

Tags: github

I've been working on a few forks of projects on github throughout the past month (each original has less than 200 stars), and it seems the original projects are inactive. When is it reasonable to make a fork your own repository?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. A fork, by definition, is your own repository.

Comment: When you need a fork you fork it.  For fork's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fork a project in Github, you make a clone of this project in your repository.

One reason to do that is when the original project is inactive (your case btw) and you need to make any kind of maintenance: resolve some bug, include new feature or adapt some specific code to fit in your own projects.

At this point you might be asking yourself: Why do a fork if I can create a new repository and copy everything to it? And the answer for that is because giving credits to something that another person did is the right thing to do! Forking makes clear that you 'borrowed' code from someone else. You still get credit for your modifications and another programmer can make use of it in the future.

Comment: Do you think there's any benefit to converting to your own repository? Perhaps to have all the commits show on your profile, or it might get more attention.

Comment: I don't see so much benefit in making the conversion. You're still able to see all the commits in the original repository. It doesn't make much difference.